# EntityFramework Filter a list by id

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have this function:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("")]
/// <summary>
/// Create a team
/// </summary>
/// <param name="model">The team model</param>
/// <returns>The modified team model</returns>
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Create(TeamBindingViewModel model)
{

    // If our model is invalid, return the errors
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest(ModelState);

    // Get all our colours
    var colours = await this.colourService.GetAllAsync();

    // Create our new model
    var team = new Team()
    {
        Name = model.Name,
        Sport = model.Sport
    };

    // For each colour, Add to our team
    team.Colours = colours.Join(model.Colours, c => c.Id, m => m.Id, (c, m) => new Colour { Id = c.Id, Hex = c.Hex, Name = c.Name }).ToList();

    // Create our team
    this.service.Create(team);

    // Save our changes
    await this.unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();

    // Assign our Id to our model
    model.Id = team.Id;

    // Return Ok
    return Ok(model);
}
```

If I run it, then EntityFramework enters new colours into the database rather than referencing the colours.
I know this is because I am creating a **new Colour** in my join.
If I change my function to this:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("")]
/// <summary>
/// Create a team
/// </summary>
/// <param name="model">The team model</param>
/// <returns>The modified team model</returns>
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Create(TeamBindingViewModel model)
{

    // If our model is invalid, return the errors
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest(ModelState);

    // Get all our colours
    var colours = await this.colourService.GetAllAsync();

    // Create our new model
    var team = new Team()
    {
        Name = model.Name,
        Sport = model.Sport
    };

    // For each colour, Add to our team
    team.Colours = colours;

    // Create our team
    this.service.Create(team);

    // Save our changes
    await this.unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();

    // Assign our Id to our model
    model.Id = team.Id;

    // Return Ok
    return Ok(model);
}
```

Everything works fine.
The only thing that is changed in the second snippet is :

```
team.Colours = colours.Join(model.Colours, c => c.Id, m => m.Id, (c, m) => new Colour { Id = c.Id, Hex = c.Hex, Name = c.Name }).ToList();
```

became

```
team.Colours = colours;
```

which is the list retrieved from the database. EntityFramework knows that this has not been changed so it just references the colours instead of creating new ones.
How can I get my filtered list to do the same?

Cheers,
/r3plica

Comment: I would ask, what is the larger problem you are trying to solve?  I can't tell from your `join` what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I knew it was simple.
I changed the problem line to this:

```
// For each colour, Add to our team
team.Colours = colours.Where(m => model.Colours.Any(c => c.Id == m.Id)).ToList();
```